# Couldn't unmarshal xml to a dynamically created struct using reflection in Golang

Tags: xml, go, struct, reflection

This is my code for parsing xml. At the end of the function, I should have values of fields of a struct in the values slice.

```
func FindAttrs(attrs []Tag, errorChan chan<- error) {
    var tableFields []reflect.StructField
    for _, v := range attrs {
        tableFields = append(tableFields, reflect.StructField{
            Name:      strings.Title(v.Name),
            Type:      reflect.TypeOf(""),
            Tag:       reflect.StructTag(fmt.Sprintf(`xml:"%v,attr"`, v.Name)),
            Offset:    0,
            PkgPath:   "utility",
            Index:     nil,
            Anonymous: false,
        })
    }
    unmarshalStruct := reflect.Zero(reflect.StructOf(tableFields))
    err := xml.Unmarshal(ReadBytes(errorChan), &unmarshalStruct)
    HandleError(err, "Error parse config", false, errorChan)
    values := make([]interface{}, unmarshalStruct.NumField())
    for i := 0; i < unmarshalStruct.NumField(); i++ {
        values[i] = unmarshalStruct.Field(0).Interface()
    }
}
```

But, it panics with the following message:

```
reflect.Value.Interface: cannot return value obtained from unexported field or method
```

I call it with:

```
utility.FindAttrs([]utility.Tag{
        {"name", reflect.String}, {"isUsed", reflect.String},
    }, errorChan)
```

And my xml is `<configuration name="mur" isUsed="mur"/>`

Comment: *"cannot return value obtained from **unexported** field"* -- means you either have to export the field, or just not do what you want to do.

Comment: I capitalized fields, you can see it in the code.

Comment: @Intolighter Coudl you try also printing the (dynamically-created) struct with `%+v` and maybe `%#v`, just to double-check what field names you ended up with?

Comment: My bad, I see now that you're using strings.Title. But there are multiple issues with your code: 1. Drop the field's PkgPath, that's there for unexported fields. 2. You're unmarshaling into `*reflect.Value` instead of the generated struct type, that ain't gonna do what you expect it to, i.e. the fields Name and IsUsed will not be populated by unmarshal because they are not the fields of the reflect.Value struct type. 3. You're passing always the 0th field to the ith value in the loop. There are possibly other errors that I haven't spotted.

Comment: @mkopriva I deleted useless attributes, but I didn't understand what you meant by unmarshalling into ```*reflect.Value````. What do I need to do?

Comment: `reflect.Zero` returns a `reflect.Value`, and `reflect.Value` is a generic representation of the underlying value, it is *not* the actual value. So `&unmrshalStruct` is of type `*reflect.Value`, it is *not* of type `*struct { Name string, IsUsed string }` which is what you want and need.

Comment: Use `reflect.New(reflect.StructOf(tableFields)).Interface()` to get `*struct{ Name string, IsUsed string}` and note this  is already a pointer so you can omit the `&` when passing it to Unmarshal.

Comment: Yea, it works, but how do I parse it?

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/fxzP7lbmaJF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to make a pointer to struct instead of a value and pass pointer's value, which can by retrieved `Interface()` function, to Unmarshal instead of it itself.

```
var tableFields []reflect.StructField
    for _, v := range attrs {
        tableFields = append(tableFields, reflect.StructField{
            Name: strings.Title(v.Name),
            Type: reflect.TypeOf(""),
            Tag:  reflect.StructTag(fmt.Sprintf(`xml:"%v,attr"`, v.Name)),
        })
    }

    rv := reflect.New(reflect.StructOf(tableFields)) // initialize a pointer to the struct

    v := rv.Interface() // get the actual value
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(`<configuration name="foo" isUsed="bar"/>`), v)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    rv = rv.Elem() // dereference the pointer
    values := make([]interface{}, rv.NumField())
    for i := 0; i < rv.NumField(); i++ {
        values[i] = rv.Field(i).Interface()
    }
```